# How can I read one byte from stdin in Dyalog APL?

Tags: input, user-input, stdin, apl, dyalog

I’m trying to make a terminal user interface in Dyalog APL and need a way to read a single byte of user input from stdin. How can I do this? In Python for example, you can use `sys.stdin.read(1)`.

I’ve tried using `⍞`, but that reads a whole line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`⎕ARBIN`](http://help.dyalog.com/18.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/arbin.htm), which can be used like this:

> [number of bytes to read] [tie number of file to read from] `⎕ARBIN` [bytes to output before reading from input]

The number of bytes to read is `1`, and there are no bytes to output (`⍬`). You can assign a tie number to stdin with [`⎕NTIE`](http://help.dyalog.com/18.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/ntie.htm).

```
stdin←'/dev/stdin' ⎕NTIE 0
byte←⊃1 stdin ⎕ARBIN ⍬
```

`⎕ARBIN` returns a numeric vector, so First (`⊃`) is used to get the byte as a scalar.